# Antlr4 generated java code visitor pattern confusion

Tags: java, antlr4, visitor-pattern

When antlr generates java code for visitor pattern, we get a base visitor class.

```java
public class YxBaseVisitor<T> extends AbstractParseTreeVisitor<T> implements YxVisitor<T> {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * <p>The default implementation returns the result of calling
     * {@link #visitChildren} on {@code ctx}.</p>
     */
    @Override public T visitProgram(YxParser.ProgramContext ctx) { return visitChildren(ctx); }
}
```

I have a derived class called `ASTBuilder` from `YxBaseVisitor`. So when I need to use the `ASTBuilder` to visit the `ParseTree` node, I will call function

```java
            ParseTree parseTreeRoot = parser.program();
            ASTBuilder astBuilder = new ASTBuilder(gScope);
            ASTRoot = (RootNode)astBuilder.visit(parseTreeRoot);
```

This piece of code calls the `visit` method of `ASTBuilder`, but `ASTBuilder` didn't define `visit` method, instead, it inherit `visit` from `AbstractParseTreeVisitor`, which is also generated by antlr.

However, the `visit` is define with `return null;`, and I didn't find other override of visit to distribute different types of `ParseTree` node.

How did the visit pattern work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it inherit visit from AbstractParseTreeVisitor, which is also generated by antlr.

`AbstractParseTreeVisitor` is not generated, it's part of the runtime library. `YxVisitor` and `YxBaseVisitor` are the ones that are being generated.

> However, the `visit` is define with `return null;`

I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion, but that's not true. It's actually defined as `return tree.accept(this);` ([source](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java#L18)).

Now, the `accept` method that's being called here will be overridden in each of the generated tree classes to call the corresponding `visitFoo` method in `YxVisitor`, e.g. `ProgramContext.accept` will be overridden to call `YxVisitor.visitProgram(this)` and that's how your `visitProgram` method ends up being called.